# Release c# app with SQLIte db to run on ot

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite

I created c# application in which use SQLite database. I opted for SQLIte because the application is intended to be copied to another computer that doesn't have SQL Server.

My program run smoothly on my computer where it's been created but I faced a problem when I copied a released folder with .exe file to another computer and try to run the program there.

Error message that I see says:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: unable to open database file...

Do I need to install SQLite on another computer where the app will be using? If so, can someone give me an instruction how to do it? Is it "Precompiled Binaries for Windows" - if I download dll where it should be placed?
If someone is experienced with SQLIte some instructions would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The message tells you "unable to open **database** file".

Comment: Yes I know what it means but I'm asking why it happens. On the end user computer where the program is copied there is no SQLIte installed. Is it required on all machines where the program will be running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message "unable to open database file" is generated by the SQLite library, so you know that it runs and does not need to be installed.

The problem is with the database file itself; it's likely that you have specified a wrong directory in the connection string.